# Python, tkinter: correct way to asynchronously modify GUI?

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, asynchronous, tkinter

this is my first question on SO. I'm trying to solve a UI problem and have a (i think) kind of specific question. In order to simplify things and clarify my reasoning let me describe an example while leaving out irrelevant parts of the application I want to solve this problem for:

Let's say we have a really small Python application that uses tkinter as a GUI. All it does is, if the user clicks on a button "Create file" and if the file does not exist, it asks the user whether the file should be created or not using messagebox.askyesno(). The file handling is done by a separate FileHandler() class that has no notion of any UI and uses Python queues to communicate asynchronously. This is to make the UI easily interchangable and I'd like to keep that aspect.

Our tk main root queries an output queue and puts the result of the message box into an input queue. This does not work using threading however because methods that affect the GUI can only be called from the main loop.

So I ended up polling the output queue using Widget.after() and doing the file handlig stuff in a separate thread to avoid deadlocking. This works, but is this considered a good solution? I have doubts because

1. It seems to burn CPU time unnecessarily (~1% constantly on my setup according to top, using a 50ms interval)
2. It's somewhat unresponsive. In the worst case the user has to wait for the full interval time until the message box appears. Shorten the interval and CPU overhead increases

Basically I want to create message boxes asynchronously without the overhead of polling. Isn't there a better solution that avoids it?

Here's my example code (tested with Python 3.4.2):

main.py

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from filehandler import FileHandler

class MyGUI():

    poll_id = None
    fh = None

    def poll(self):
            self.poll_cancel()
            try:
                notification = self.fh.outqueue.get_nowait()
            except:
                self.poll_id = self.root.after(50, self.poll)
                return
            if notification == 1:
                yesno = messagebox.askyesno("Question",
                "Do you want to create the file?")
                self.fh.inqueue.put(yesno)
            self.fh.outqueue.task_done()
            self.poll_id = self.root.after(50, self.poll)

    def poll_cancel(self):
        if self.poll_id is not None:
            self.root.after_cancel(self.poll_id)
            self.poll_id = None

    def create_file(self):
        self.fh.create_file()

    def __init__(self, fh):
        self.fh = fh
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.btn = Button(self.root, text="Open file",
        command=self.create_file)
        self.root.btn.pack()

        self.poll()

        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyGUI(FileHandler())
```

filehandler.py

```
import os
import queue
import threading

class FileHandler():        

    inqueue = None
    outqueue = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.inqueue = queue.Queue()
        self.outqueue = queue.Queue()

    def create_file(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self.create_file_thread).start()

    def create_file_thread(self):
        if not os.path.exists("file"):
            self.outqueue.put(1)
            yesno = self.inqueue.get()
            if yesno == 1:
                try:
                    with open("file", 'a'):
                        os.utime("file")
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
            self.inqueue.task_done()
```

Comment: Why would you want to complicate things for a "a really small Python application" with using threads, queses, etc? Probably the "better solution" would be not to use  threads for something as simple as creating a single file.

Comment: @Marcin in the example i left out all the unneccessary parts of the application that i actually want to find the solution for. but the basic problem remains the same. if someone has a solution for my example without threads and queues, but with the message box, i would be more than happy! made it a bit clearer in the question.

Comment: Actually you can remove one queue: just start the thread after starting main-loop to avoid synchronization on `outqueue`.  And although you cannot directly *modify* GUI from another thread (unlsee you do it within a `widget.after_idle()`), you CAN interrogate its values.  So maybe your original code gets even simpler.

But still, we need an explanation why the current code is hogging you cpu and is not responsive.  Have you tried longer polling delay than 50ms?